# Persistent Touchbar with Electron

Tags: electron, macbookpro-touch-bar

Can an Electron app present a persistent touchbar layout across applications?

[With the sample code here](https://github.com/Rawnly/touchbar-api-sample) I'm able to interact with touch bar elements while the app is foregrounded, but the buttons disappear when switching to another application.

[Projects like MTMR](https://github.com/Toxblh/MTMR) written natively allow for custom touchbar configurations that stay active across all apps.

I don't see a similar mechanism for doing this within Electron. Is such a thing possible, or must you delve into Swift / Objective-C to achieve that functionality?

(This is for a personal project so I'm not worried about using private APIs, though again I'm not sure if Electron enables such a thing.)